# distinct ef4,convert a sql to linq

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

how can I make this sql with linq?

```
select distinct(BAIRRO),id,MUNICIPIO from LOGRADOURO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from l in LOGRADUORO
             select l.ID, l.BAIRRO, l.MUNICIPIO).Distinct();
```